# Function argument type deduction across several arguments of function type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following (minimal, hence not very useful) example:

```
type UnaryFunc<X,Z> = (x: X) => Z;
type BinaryFunc<X,Y,Z> = (x: X, y: Y) => Z;

function F<P,Q,R1,R2> ( f1: UnaryFunc<P,R1>, f2: BinaryFunc<Q,P,R2> ):
(p: P, q: Q, r1: R1, r2: R2) => number {
  return (p, q, r1, r2) => 99;
}

const f = F (
  <P> (pary: P[]) => pary[0],
  <Q> (q: Q, pary: Q[]) => [q, ...pary]
)
```

The type of the first parameter of the first argument of `F` is supposed to be the same as the type of second argument of the second parameter of `F` (both `P` in the declaration of `F`). That is a constraint on how `F` is supposed to be called.

Now I expect the type of `f` to be inferred as something like

```
<P> (p: P[], q: P, r1: P, r2: P[]) => number
```

What I actually get, however, is

```
<P> (p: P[], q: unknown, r1: P, r2: unknown[]) => number
```

How can I change the definition of `F` or the type annotations in the `const f = ...` statement in order to make Typescript correctly infer the types of `q` and `r2` ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible; TypeScript doesn't have full unification (as requested in [ms/TS#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134). The support for higher order function inference implemented in [ms/TS#30215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) has limitations, notably it only works if "in the left-to-right processing of the function call arguments, no inferences have been made for any of the type parameters referenced in the contextual type for the argument expression.", which isn't true for your second argument to `F()`.

Comment: Question posts in SO should have a single question; please consider removing your "minor question" or moving it to its own post (after searching for existing ones).  Not quite sure what you mean by it, anyway... are you asking if TypeScript already has utility types corresponding to these function types? If so, the answer is "no"; and while it might be nice if it did, TS tends only to provide such types if the compiler itself needs them in emitted declaration files.  This is an interesting topic and may be deserving of its own post.

Comment: So then, does my first comment fully address your question or am I missing something? If it addresses the question then I can turn it into an answer post when I get a chance.

Comment: Since your comment fully describes sad reality, yes, that answers my question. Thank you very much. Of course, I'd accept the answer.